# equivalent expressions for curvature

Tags: calculus, geometry

The curvature $\kappa$ can be written as $\frac{d\theta}{ds}$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent and a fixed axis, and $s$ the arclength. I cannot understand why $\kappa$ is equivalently equal to $\frac{y_{xx}}{(1+y_x)^{3/2}}$, where the subscript indicates the derivative with respect to $x$. Also, what is the expression of $\kappa_{ss}$?

Comment: $ds =\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{1+y^{'}}dx$

Answer (score 1):

Taking any parametric equation of the curve, $(x(t),y(t))$, the angle $\theta$ is given by $\arctan\left(\dot y(t)/\dot x(t)\right)$, and its derivative with respect to $s$ by

$$\theta_s
=\frac{\theta_t}{s_t}
=\frac{\ddot y(t)\dot x(t)-\dot y(t)\ddot x(t)}{\dot y^2(t)\left(1+\frac{\dot y^2(t)}{\dot x^2(t)}\right)\sqrt{\dot x^2(t)+\dot y^2(t)}}
=\frac{\ddot y(t)\dot x(t)-\dot y(t)\ddot x(t)}{\left(\dot x^2(t)+\dot y^2(t)\right)^{3/2}}.$$

Now setting $x=t$, this simplifies with $\dot x=1,\ddot x=0,\dot y=y',\ddot y=y''$:

$$\frac{y''(x)}{\left(1+y'^2(x)\right)^{3/2}}.$$

To deduce $\kappa_{ss}$, you can use the planar Frenet-Serret formulas (parameterized with the arc length):

$$T_s=\kappa N\\N_s=-\kappa T,$$
and derive twice 
$$\kappa_s=(T_sN)_s=T_{ss}N+T_sN_s=T_{ss}N,$$
$$\kappa_{ss}=(T_{ss}N)_s=T_{sss}N+T_{ss}N_s=T_{sss}N-\kappa T_{ss}T.$$

Comment: Why $s_t =\sqrt{\dot x^2 + \dot y^2}$? I thought that $ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$.

Comment: @user36390: right, it's the same.